# Determining rank (position) attribute for ordered lists

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, position, rank

An ordered list is stored in a client-side database that doesn't preserve order (think sqlite table). Multiple versions of the list will be stored and edited concurrently, and occasionally merged. To keep order in the face of concurrent edits, a rank (position) attribute is used to sort the list.

What should the `rank` attribute look like? What algorithm can be used for determining a new item's `rank` when inserting into the list?

### Explanation

In a todo app, multiple offline clients edit the same list but occasionally come online and sync. A todo list is an unordered set of entities, e.g.:

```
[{id: 1001, rank: 1}, {id: 1002, rank: 2}, {id: 1003, rank: 3}]
```

Through the `rank` attribute, clients can add items at arbitrary positions or re-order the list. In my example integers are used to indicate position, but any sortable JSON datatype could be used instead (strings, floats, even collections). The `id` attribute is randomly generated.

When clients come online, their lists are merged automatically. In the process, no updates should be lost and the resulting merged list should follow user expectations.

Assume the following constraints:

- Items should have a determinate sort order.
- Clients need to be able to insert todo items at any position (before the first item, after the first item, ..., after the last item).
- At no point should it become impossible to insert an item between two items.

It may be inevitable to re-number the list items when inserting new items. However, in so far as re-numbering events affect merges, surprising merge behavior should be minimized.

Comment: I stumbled upon [this article](https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-03-20-user-defined-order.html) a while back that might give you some ideas.

Comment: You have not told us what those "user expectations" are. Define "surprising".

Comment: @Shawn, that's a very good article, thanks. Especially the section on using rational numbers is interesting.

Comment: @CL, I think there's wiggle room there. I can give an example. Starting from AB, two clients insert X and Y respectively between the items. The result of merging AXB and AYB should not be XYAB — it would be surprising if the elements jumped to the beginning of the list. But both AXYB and AYXB would be acceptable merge results.